# Запятая и однородность определений

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение следующее:
***Все люди, которые имеют право и которые пройдут соответствующие(,) предусмотренные законом процедуры...***
У автора отмеченная запятая стоит, но я засомневалась в её необходимости. К сожалению, у меня весьма сложные отношения с однородностью/неоднородностью определений, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью к вам: **нужна ли данная запятая?**
P. S. Это отрывок из речи В.В. Путина по поводу грядущих президентских выборов. В публикациях СМИ запятая стоит. Но доверять им... Порой там допускают совершенно глупые ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Можно рассматривать последующее как уточнение, но и циркулярная "однородность" тоже имеет место. Зададимся вопросом: чему "соответствуют" процедуры (если не уточнять)? Если люди "имеют **право**", то соответствуют эти процедуры **закону**, что затем и раскрыто во избежание неясностей.

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта возможны:

- соответствующие, (то есть) предусмотренные законом (дла этого случая) процедуры
- (только) соответствующие предусмотренные законом процедуры (законом предусмотрены и другие процедуры, но они не соответствуют этому случаю)